# Circular dependency while installing RASA framework via pip3

Tags: python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am trying to install Rasa framework 1.6.1 on macOS but `sanic` package is having some sort of circular dependency with other packages. I am getting following error while doing `pip3 install rasa`

```
ERROR: sanic-plugins-framework 0.8.2.post1 has requirement sanic<=19.6.3,>=0.8.3, but you'll have sanic 19.12.2 which is incompatible.
```

If I manually install `sanic` 19.6.3 then it complains that it needs `sanic` lower than 19.6.3. I tried building form source but same problem comes up.

How do I sort out this dependency problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing `--system-site-packages` from virtualenv.